# Django error in filtering datetime field by date : Join on field X not permitted

Tags: python, sql, django, datetime

I saw another post suggests that datetime field can be filtered by time, by using `__date`. However when I tried on my machine it never worked.

This is my `models.py`

```
class Record (models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    user = ForeignKey to the user table
    content = models.CharField(max_length=36,null=True,blank=True,unique=True)
```

In `python manage.py.runserver`

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from appname.models import Record

>>> u = User.objects.filter(username = 'user')
>>> r = Record.objects.filter(time__date = datetime.today().date())

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 163, in filter
    return self.get_queryset().filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 590, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 608, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1198, in add_q
    clause = self._add_q(where_part, used_aliases)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1234, in _add_q
    current_negated=current_negated)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1100, in build_filter
    allow_explicit_fk=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1357, in setup_joins
    names, opts, allow_many, allow_explicit_fk)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1320, in names_to_path

    "the lookup type?" % (name, names[pos + 1]))
FieldError: Join on field 'timeIn' not permitted. Did you misspell 'date' for the lookup type?
```

I am on windows 7 running python 2.7, django 1.6

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't think you can do the way you are doing, there isn't `__date` for a datetime field.

Comment: I think i might have misread [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9596)

Answer (score 1):

Heads up, this should work as of [Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#date).

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__date=datetime.date(2005, 1, 1))
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__date__gt=datetime.date(2005, 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use __contains instead of __date:

```
r = Record.objects.filter(time__contains = datetime.today().date())
```

**UPDATE**

Since that __startswith (LIKE 'value%') is more faster than __contains (LIKE '%value%'), the best choice is:

```
r = Record.objects.filter(time__startswith = datetime.today().date())
```

Comment: Is __contains going to bring performance issues - Is it doing a string comparison? Some people suggested using __startswith but that seems to be doing a string comparison?

Comment: Humm, I just figured out that the difference between each other is that __contains became in LIKE '%value%' and __startswith in LIKE 'value%'. So, yes, there is a performance issue, and __startswith is faster.